# Difference result running Protractor from cmd vs npm run script

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, protractor, e2e-testing

Protractor is working perfectly fine when running this command:

```
$ protractor app/tests/e2e/conf.js
```

When i put this command into the `package.json` file, to make *npm* execute the command, protractor isn't working.

```
// package.json
...
"scripts": {
    "test": "protractor app/tests/e2e/conf.js"
}
```

running:

```
$ npm run test
```

Result:

*browser*

[image: chrome loading]

*console*

[image: console showing this]

Why doesn't this give the same result? It just freezes/hangs with the 'data;' text in the address bar.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, what happens if you run it as `node node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor app/tests/e2e/conf.js`?

Comment: @alecxe hmm, that gives the same result as with `npm run test`

Comment: Thanks. What if you run `node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update` and try again running `npm run test`?

Comment: @alecxe Output: `selenium standalone is up to date. chromedriver is up to date.` Running `npm run test` again I get the same result.. Just the chrome window loading with the text `data;` in the URL.

Comment: Ah, the symptoms sound awfully familiar. What output do you get if you run `node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor --version` and `protractor --version`?

Comment: @alecxe wow. genious! I wasn't aware that the local (project) version of selenium/protractor didn't match my global version. Will you post that as an answer, and i'll accept? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two `protractor` node packages installed - one is a global one and another is a local one located inside the `node_modules` directory in your project root. Run:

```
node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor --version
protractor --version
```

that would probably show you that your local `protractor` needs to be updated:

```
npm install protractor
```